# Decrypt a blob from Azure blob storage with key vault using version 12.x Azure storage libraries

Tags: c#, azure, encryption, azure-blob-storage, azure-keyvault

I am trying to download and decrypt a blob from azure blob storage using vault key just like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-encrypt-decrypt-blobs-key-vault#decrypt-blob-and-download) tutorial, except that the linked tutorial is outdated. I am using the latest `Azure.Storage.Blobs` Nuget Package and do not see any way to do this as there is no `BlobRequestOptions` or `BlobEncryptionPolicy` object or similar in the package as is seen in the tutorial. Everything that I look up points me back to the linked tutorial that is again outdated.

Here is my current code:

```cs
BlobServiceClient serviceClient = new BlobServiceClient("connectionString");
BlobContainerClient containerClient = serviceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("containerName");
BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient("blobName");
await blobClient.DownloadToAsync(myStream);
```

Somewhere in here I would like to pass in my key vault key resolver to decrypt the blob like in the tutorial.

Is there a way to do that?

If not, what is the current best way to decrypt blobs using key vault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, in `Azure.Storage.Blobs`, you can use `EncryptionScope` in `BlobClientOptions`.

In `Azure.Storage.Blobs`, you can use [`EncryptionScope`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-service-encryption#encryption-scopes-for-blob-storage-preview) in `BlobClientOptions`. You could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/encryption-scope-manage?tabs=portal) to create encryption scope. But the feature is in preview.

After configure azure storage container, you can upload blob with the specify encryption scope you created before and add the `BlobClientOptions` into `BlobServiceClient`.

[image]

```
var options = new BlobClientOptions();
options.EncryptionScope= "joeyencrypt";
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient("connectionString",options);
```

Comment: Is there a way to decrypt the blob using key vault or is this the only way to do it currently?

Comment: For now, using `Azure.Storage.Blobs` ca n  not achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.SpecializedBlobExtensions
        public static BlobClient WithClientSideEncryptionOptions(this BlobClient client, ClientSideEncryptionOptions clientSideEncryptionOptions);
```